# json yql data retrieval via php

Tags: php, json, object, yql

I'm struggle extracting necessary data from this json stored inside php variable.
Not yet expert in this kind of data structure yet...

Wondering anyone know how to make it work.

I need to loop through results, then read each contact to get 
1. the value where type=email
2. value->givenName where type=name (whenever element exist)

the json decoded value is as below

```
$aNative   = json_decode($retval);

echo "lang: " . $aNative->query->lang . "<br>"; (works)    

(when go deeper, fail to retrieve any value...)

echo "created: " .  $aNative->results->contact[0]->created . "<br>";


foreach($aNative->$query->results as $contact)
{
    echo $contact->id;
    echo $contact->fields[0]->type;

    if($contact->fields[0]->type=="email")
    {
        echo $contact->fields[0]->value;
    }

}
```

full json:

```
{
   "query":{
      "count":10,
      "created":"2012-06-13T09:13:45Z",
      "lang":"en-US",
      "results":{

         "contact":[


            {
               "created":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
               "updated":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
               "uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/BNQJOMYDQYLY2FZSMROV4QDA6MI/contact/14",
               "isConnection":"false",
               "id":"14",
               "fields":{
                  "created":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                  "updated":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                  "uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/BNQJOMYDQYLY2FZSMROV4QDA6MI/contact/14/email/11",
                  "id":"11",
                  "type":"email",
                  "value":"angBB@gmail.com",
                  "editedBy":"OWNER"
               }
            },            


            {
               "created":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
               "updated":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
               "uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/MNQJOMYDQYLY2FZSMROV4QDA6MI/contact/12",
               "isConnection":"false",
               "id":"12",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "created":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                     "updated":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                     "uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/MNQJOMYDQYLY2FZSMROV4QDA6MI/contact/12/email/6",
                     "id":"6",
                     "type":"email",
                     "value":"jaq@lifemastr.com",
                     "editedBy":"OWNER"
                  },
                  {
                     "created":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                     "updated":"2006-10-29T04:32:07Z",
                     "uri":"http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/MNQJOMYDQYLY2FZSMROV4QDA6MI/contact/12/name/5",
                     "id":"5",
                     "type":"name",
                     "value":{
                        "givenName":"'Jaq'",
                        "middleName":null,
                        "familyName":null,
                        "prefix":null,
                        "suffix":null,
                        "givenNameSound":null,
                        "familyNameSound":null
                     },
                     "editedBy":"OWNER"
                  }
               ]
            } 



         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten about `query`. You have to access to results for example in this way:

```
$aNative->query->results->contact[0]->created
```

And review whole your code you are trying to access to wrong properties many times. For example in foreach you shall use `$aNative->query->results->contact` instead of `$aNative->results` because `results` it is an object and not array.

Comment: I'm facing another challenge, Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.... Believe due to the first contact don't have fields[0] and fields[1], any idea to get around?

Comment: In first `contact` `fields` is object, in second and third they are array, so before using `fields` field check is it array or object. So use [is_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) and if it is true use `->` otherwise you can use `foreach` or go by indexes.